# Datagridview NullReferenceException Error when renewing in timer

Tags: c#, datagridview, nullreferenceexception

I have an application where I need to get a certain number as a reference value to send to PLC. To do that I get all the rows from the database and list them on my datagridview (dgv) and with a timer I reload the datagridview with updated rows. To load the data I use the code below;

```
public void updatedgv()
        {
            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Program.sqlcon))
                {
                    string q = "SELECT CONCAT(RL.istekID,'-',RL.lineID) '#',M.makName 'Makine Adı',R.partiNo 'PartiNo',C.kimAd 'Kimyasal',RL.miktar 'Miktar',RL.durum 'Durum', RL.lineID 'Kuyruk No' FROM RECLN RL JOIN REC R ON    RL.istekID=R.istekID JOIN MAK M ON R.makID=M.makID JOIN CHEM C ON C.kimID=RL.kimID WHERE RL.durum IN (1,2)";
                    using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(q, con))
                    {
                        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed) { con.Open(); } else { con.Close(); con.Open(); }
                        using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(com))
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                dt = new DataTable();
                                sda.Fill(dt);
                                dgv.DataSource = dt;
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex) { this.Text = ex.Message; }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { this.Text = ex.Message; }
        }
```

But once in a while, it gives the error below and my application stops working.

```
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
```

I have tried everything to avoid the problem but unfortunately, I couldn't find what I need to do.

I believe I am doing something wrong with my code but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: I read this one and it was useful to me but this one couldn't help me to find the solution. I am using this method where I have updated any records on the database with delay but couldn't solve also. Still crashing with same error.

Comment: Well... if you are 100% sure the error is coming from the posted code... then... what line of code throws this error... there are not that many places in the posted code "where" this error would be thrown. The error, when thrown, "should" tell you which line of code threw the error. This is the only way to "isolate" where the culprit is especially if the error is not consistent.

Comment: Usually this part ```dgv.DataSource = dt;``` but most of the time crashes at Program.cs at ```Application.Run(new frmMain());```  I am using the datagrid to show  que information. with ```dgv.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString()``` and I believe when this value is not able to read the error occuers.

Comment: _”Usually this part”_ … ? … what part? … If you can not tell us which line of code throws the error, I suggest you create a [mre] that reproduces the error. It would be pure speculation otherwise. If you are not familiar with “debugging” your code… now would be a good time to learn. When know it is a `null` exception… but “which” line of code throws this error? Saying the error is in _“this part”_ … isn’t going to help us help you.

Comment: Copy the Details which contain stack trace  will help to identify where is the problem come from and add it to your question

Comment: I am testing at the moment to get the details from stack trace but the error sometimes occurs at startup but sometimes after 30 minutes or so. I will be back with the Stack trace.

Comment: Strictly speaking, none of this code is needed.  If you have a persistent DataAdapter, you can refresh the view very, very simply.  The manufactured/virtual columns might be problematic (never tried with them)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put more effort into your question, it *wastes time of people who could help and makes it difficult to answer*, when it's not clear.

I suspect there's couple of things fundamentally wrong with your design.

First of all, if you need only some data from the database, then don't pull all the table to be processed (aka taken one value from it), but rather put the filter into the SQL statement and get one scallar value (or reduced result set, whatever is appropriate).

To answer the question, to avoid the error you get (provided it's from the reading that cell you mentioned, which is actually quite probable), you simply need to ensure you're reading existing cell and existing value:

```
if (dgv.Rows.Count > 0)  // check row exists, to work with a row
{
    DataGridViewRow irow = dgv.Rows(0);
    if (dgv.Columns.Count > 0)    // check column exists, to work with a row
    {
        // Dim icol As DataGridViewColumn = dgv.Columns(0)   ' <<< if column reference needed
        DataGridViewCell icell = irow.Cells(0);
        if (!IsDBNull(icell) && !IsNothing(icell))  // check cell is not empty
            myResult = icell.Value.ToString();// <<< Mind datatypes and type conversions! Not shown here!
    }
}
```

My guess is, that once in a while you get a `dbnull` value in that cell and your program crashes.

Comment: Thanks that solved my problem and I also reduced readings. I only read the table when it is needed. Now I made it run around 4 hours and no errors so far